# Вычислить возраст по дате рождения

Tags: sql, postgresql

В СУБД `postrgesql 9.3` в таблице `users` есть поле `birthday` тип `date`.

Попробовал запрос

```
  SELECT DATE_PART('year','2018-12-01'::date) - DATE_PART('year','1989-12-22'::date)
```

ответ `29`, а фактически возраст пользователя `28`, ему еще не исполнилось `29`

Можно ли вычислить реальный возраст по дате рождения?

Comment: Добрый день. А зачем нагружать этим вычисление sql? Может будет лучше это сделать уже после запроса, на сервере и отдать клиенту готовый результат?

Comment: Так не пробовали: `SELECT date_part('year',age('1989-12-22'::date))` ?

Comment: @MaxU спасибо подошло, можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `age()` и вычленить год из результата:

```
SELECT date_part('year',age('1989-12-22'::date))
```